# Interface builder is not opening in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I updated xcode version 9 on last friday. Everything is working fine, but when i am clicking on main.storyboard, it takes lot of time but still not opened. When i check my Activity monitor, the interface builder takes 11.39GB?

What should i do? I am unable to design my new screens.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to close / terminate your xcode and launch it again. sometimes it appears, that the indexing processing files takes a lot of time

Comment: Maybe reimport the project?

Comment: AlexWoe89.. i have already closed 6 times and also restart my computer..but doesn't work.

Comment: Did you clean the project/clean the build folder/deleted the Derived Data folder?

Comment: the4kman.. Already Cleaned... Cmd+option+shift+K... but not working.

Comment: If you were able to edit the storyboard in Xcode 8 and took all the usual maintenance measures mentioned here please file a bug report. IB has serious problems in Xcode 9 and the more people complain officially at Apple, the better.

Answer (score 0):

- Close Xcode
- Open Terminal and enter this command

  rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

  This is worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, this failed for me.